# KEIL ~ Undefined symbol os_set_env

Tags: c, assembly, keil, undefined-symbol

Using Keil with a KL46Z board I get these errors ...

```
.\Flash\Blinky.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol os_set_env (referred from pr05.o).
.\Flash\Blinky.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol rt_sys_init (referred from pr05.o).
Not enough information to list image symbols.
```

... when I try to build this code:

```
#include "helper.h"
#include <rtl.h>

__task void init (void) {

}

int main (void) {
    os_sys_init (init);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not linking with whatever library that contains the symbols you miss?

Comment: I think I am including the right library. Here is an example: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_os_sys_init.htm

Comment: @Sergio, Someprogrammerdude was referring about linking, not `#include`ing.

Comment: How are you building it? What flags are you passing the compiler?